# Word for 'approach boldly' or 'take on' something new?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

I am looking for a word that can express the idea of 'approaching' a new idea boldly or 'taking it on'.

I want to use it as (assuming the word is XYZ):

> 'this shows my ability to XYZ unfamiliar concepts and applying them
>   successfully'

Comment: You need the infinitive *apply* there, to match *to XYZ*. What have you looked up and discarded so far? How about *handle*?

Comment: @AndrewLeach, I was thinking like `my ability to *approach* unfamiliar ideas` but it seemed tepid, and not give the sense of taking head on Did I make sense?

Comment: Yes, but please do check the [single-word-requests help](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) -- you added that tag quite correctly.

Comment: Tackle, comprehend, wrestle or grapple with, master

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps, ***embrace*** helps here.

> 'this shows my ability to ***embrace*** unfamiliar concepts and
>   applying them successfully'

ODO:

> **[embrace](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/embrace)**
>   *VERB*
>
> **2** *Accept (a belief, theory, or change) willingly and enthusiastically*:
>   ‘besides traditional methods, artists are
>   embracing new technology’
>
> ‘Maybe we will benefit beyond belief in embracing some of these
>   valuable philosophies and using them in practical solutions for all
>   our welfare.’